# ED25519 private key length in different implementations

Tags: openssl

I seem to have some confusion around ED25519 private keys in different implementations. Both Bouncy Castle as well as OpenSSL generate 32 byte private keys. However libSodium seems to want 64 byte private keys, as does ST's crypto library (see UM1924).

So how are these systems interoperable in regards to this?

Comment: As far as I know the public and the private are 32 bytes, and the signature generated is 64 bytes. Did you try to ask this question on crypto.exchange.com?

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/54367

Comment: Hmm, so according to the above it's an encoding thing. In any case, a Bouncy created signature can be checked with the ST crypto library. So, so far so good... As long as I don't need to to sign anything now I'm good.

Answer (score 3):

I just realize that the private key generated by libSodium got appended by its public key hence the total length is 64 bytes. I've tried to append the public key generated by Bouncy Castle into the private key so it's 64 bytes long and it works. Referring to this answer [An Ed25519 private key consists of a 32 byte seed (from which you can cheaply derive the 32 byte private scalar and the 32 byte hash prefix) and the 32 byte public key.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/54354)